# Odd minus style when drawing american voltage

Tags: symbols, positioning, circuitikz, alignment

Looking closely at the image produced by circuitikz, I find that the minus sign of an american voltage looks rather odd. The alignment seems off and the sign seems much too wide. Is there a way to align the minus sign to the horizontal line of the plus sign and make it just as wide?

[image: Produced image]

This is the code snippet that reproduces the result:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
        \draw
        (4,-1) to[short] (4,-2)
        (5,-1) to[short] (5,-2);
        \draw (4,-2) to[open,v_>=$U_S$] (5,-2);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `pgfcircvoltage.tex`, lines 190-210: one sign is set in normal size, the other in `\scriptsize`. One should patch these. But maybe it _is_ a standard american notation (I have absolutely no idea).

Comment: I'll look at it when I have time. Can you open an issue at github? https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues (it seems a bug...)

Comment: Thank you, @campa! Modifying the pgfcircvoltage.tex file (removing those \scriptsize commands) indeed resolved the problem. So it's not really a bug, just an unusual design choice. @Rmano, unfortunately I don't have a github account (deleted it after Microsoft stepped in).

Comment: I opened an issue myself: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/193 . @campa, if you write an answer I'll be happy to cite it in the bug solution... I am thinking of making the sizes configurable (but coherent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug; thanks for noticing. The new version will have this fixed and, as a bonus, a way to customize the appearance of the symbols.

See https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/196